# How to detect "MINIMAL" cycles in a graph

Tags: graph

I have a question regarding graphs.

I have a street network (imagine Manhattan, NY as an example, but it could be any street network) represented as a graph (where junctions are represented as nodes und the streets are links between the nodes).

The problem now is that I somehow have to get the "city blocks" (think of the blocks in Manhattan for instance), i.e. the set of arcs that define a city block. I thought of cycle detection algorithms but that obviously won't give me the real blocks only, but also all the other cycles that I don't really need. Of course I could filter those out probably quite easily but this can't be the real solution.

Do you have any (simple) idea how I can get the "real" city block from a graph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: doesn't [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=minimal+cycles+in+a+graph) say enought about the topic?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute a minimum point of a curve equation?

Comment: I am sorry. I wasn't aware that "minimal" is actually a term used in graph theory, so problem solved. Thanks.